Can dark matter around astronomical bodies like galaxies be explained by the Reissner-Nordstrom effect?
According to Reissner-Nordstrom solution to Einstein's gravitational field equations in astronomy the electric or magnetic or both, field of a charged body of mass generates its own gravitational field in addition to the gravitational field created by the mass of the body.
I wonder if the radiation field of a galaxy around its surrounding vacuum using the Reissner-Nordstrom effect could quantitatively and effectively explain the additional mass needed to explain the anomalous rotation speed of the galaxy without the use and hypothesis of the presence of exotic dark matter?

Dark matter is simply a parameter in the equations representing mass, which we understand quite well.  Exotic matter is a completely different concept, and we don't even know how it should work.  Your first task it not to confuse the two things!

The RN solution involves very strong fields (energy densities comparable to the mass density). Normal galaxies do not exhibit signs of very strong electric or magnetic fields.

More on dark matter & EM.

Dark matter spreads out in vast distances from the planets and stars from a galaxy.  It would be difficult to see how the electric or magnetic fields emanating from those masses would spread so far.
